# How can I make a program that's impossible to be killed in Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

We are making a Jabber client for our internal use in our company and somehow we need to catch the moment when the user tries to kill the program to actually restart it or just make impossible for the user to kill the client.

Is this possible?

Our Jabber client will be written in C#.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Why? This sounds like horrible horrible design that people will want to kill you for.

Comment: Yeap, but is requested by policy :(

Comment: Why is the client insisting that the application not be "killed". You could just give them a regular application, and not have any obivous means of exiting. (that's a terrible UX, but it's possible) but if I user wants to go to the task manager and kill the process, you should always let them.

Comment: devinb: Thats not necessarily true. If I have bone-head users, I don't want them to kill their virus scanners.

Comment: @Alan: you're right. we should also not allow drivers to steer their cars where they want, and stop them using knives in ways we've decided they can't. There should be absolutely no personal choice or responsibility and we should have absolutely no say in what we do, regardless of how stupid.

Comment: @David Hoffman - look to the spirit of the policy versus the letter.

Comment: It will clearly piss of those users who would like to leave the chat for a while and finally get some work done :)

Comment: @Alan, that's their choice, and even if they don't understand what they are doing, they at least know that they are somewhere they don't know... So let them be stupid, let them think.
totaly agree with you Jeff Yates

Comment: First, you'll have to weld the power plug to the outlet.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What you are asking for has implications far beyond what you are being asked to accomplish. For example, if the process cannot be killed, how can Windows shut down normally?

I don't know your boss, so you will have to gauge their level of understanding for yourself. If a user/manager asked me for this, I would have to probe deeper to find what they really mean. My suspicion is that your users want the default close behavior to minimize to the system tray rather than exit the program, similar to most instant message clients, rather then not be able to ever close the program at all.

Comment: Exactly what I thought when I read the question - if the app won't die by user action, how would Windows be able to close it when shutting down?

Answer (score 31):

let me first say, this is a horrible idea.

but...if you must do it, the way I see malicious software and spam hounds do it is to create 3 running processes, one is the main process and the other two will monitor and restart any killed process.  it's very difficult for the average user to kill 3 processes simultaneously.

Comment: Can I somehow let the running process detect if the user is trying to shut down so that it can close itself, without affecting a proper shutdown?

Answer (score 22):

Sounds like a virus.

Answer (score 13):

Since this is internal, you could create a separate windows service that monitors the active processes. If the process of your jabber client isn't there, you could just relaunch it.

Then use permissions to keep them from accessing the Windows Service to disable it.

Answer (score 7):

I think you should go ask the requirement designer what they mean by app that is impossible to "kill."  What are they getting at with the word "kill"?

- Not allowing a user to close their program

  - Prevent standard use of X button in window?
  - Minimize to task tray?
  - Not allow them to close the app in Task Manager?
- Not allowing the OS to close their program

The requirement is ambiguous enough that I'd go talk to the requirement designer/boss to get a better idea of what they want.

Answer (score 6):

Not only does this sound like a bad idea (it is abusive to your users) but you will not be able to prevent users from killing the process itself.

You would have to run two separate processes - one to run the application and a second one to monitor the first one and restart it if necessary.

Comment: If you are so sure of what you are saying then it's enough for me. But I do agree with you though :(

Comment: And then a third to watch the second... :)

Comment: @David - It sounds like you are caught up in an unfortunate situation, I am truly sorry about that.  Just try to make the best of it.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  You can make it harder, but not impossible.  See [The arms race between programs and users](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to reduce their user rights until they can't kill processes.

Answer (score 3):

Control it with a Windows Service. Easy to do in C#. Lock down permissions to stop the service.

Note: I think the answers of "this is impossible/horrible/evil" are perhaps missing your point. A service is specifically designed 'keep going', which is what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2):

More importantly, WHY are you rewriting a jabber client when so many good ones, like Miranda and Pidgin already exist?  If it's for logging, you can easily do that server side on your Jabber server, and not rely on the clients.

If it's to prevent other IM services, robust firewall rules will help stop that (but it won't prevent it from the super geniuses who'll proxy AIM+Gtalk over https to their home servers).

Answer (score 1):

You can catch most signals with handlers, except for SIGKILL.

You can create a watch dog windows process that respawns your application in the event it's terminated.

If you want, you can name this process something very innocuous sounding like "sysmon" so it doesn't look as sketchy.

I do hope this is a requirement for work, and not your way to bringing about the downfall of man.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you have access to the jabber client. Can you make it poll to a separate location with it's status and startup time? You aren't disabling the ability to kill it... but at least you can track it and respond from there.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this be controlled by your desktop group?  We have PCs in a few kiosks that allow associates to check personal e-mail and stuff (Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, etc...), and the user permissions on those PCs will not allow users to kill processes.

Kind of annoying if IE locks up, but I can understand the reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a case of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/03/54760.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Promise to suspend the users who kill your <s>traffic logger</s> Jabber client?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is an **awful idea**.

Having said that, you'd create **two programs** (probably **windows services**). Both programs would monitor each other as well as functioning as the client. You would need **shared memory** that both processes could access to synch which client processes incoming requests.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can prevent from the users to run TaskManager by GPO.
2. You can create your application as a Windows Service and prevent from the user kill the task manualy  ( can be killed only from the services.msc )
3. Try to tie their hands  :- )

Answer (score 0):

go to actions and make a form closing event and in c# type e.cancel = true;

Answer (score -2):

Unless you're really writing a virus, you should be able to block their ability to kill the process with permissions. Assuming they are all domain users and you are the admin.

I guess there would be a few cases where you would want to do this. You don't want users making security vulnerabilities. I can't exit or change any settings of Norton endpoint on my work computer, and it hasn't bothered me yet.

But if all the users are admins on their machines, and you want to make it impossible to close, and presumably impossible to start in safe made and remove... then you're asking: "How do I write malware?"

Comment: also, not the same as removing steering wheels from cars....more like gluing the headlights to AUTO